# How to find the index of a bi-gram in a sentence

Tags: java, search

I want to search for a bi-gram in a sentence and find its index. For example, take the following sentence:

> in the absence of functional studies it is not possible at present to conclude that
>   drug is a disease-related drug.

Here am trying to search for "is a" and not "is" as there there is "is" and "is a" in the sentence.

I currently use ArrayList to store  the sentence and use "equals" and "contains" for comparison but the result is that I pick up the index of is and returns 7 and not the index of "is a". I use Java in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This would get you index (number of charatcers) of "is a" in a very simple way

```
 int index= "in the absence of functional studies it is not possible at present to conclude that drug is a disease-related drug.".indexOf("is a");
```

When you start splitting by whitespace, you need to start caring about punctuation too...
Natural language processig is much more complicated, you should take a look at http://lucene.apache.org/core/